# Having (part of) the dependent variable as independent variable

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

Hope you can help me with this, I am running a panel fixed effects regression of the sort:

$log\left(\frac{Y_{it}+D_{it}-I_{it}}{X_{it}}\right)=\alpha+\pi_i+\beta log \left(X_{it}\right)+\gamma log\left(\frac{D_{it}}{X_{it}}\right)+\theta log \left(\frac{Z_{it}}{X_{it}}\right)+\phi DUMMY_{it}+\epsilon_{it}$

i is the firm and t is time. So there is some overlap between dependent and independent variables, but what I am looking for is only the coefficient $\phi$ on the dummy variable. The rest is merely controls. Does anyone know whether this is a problem, and what it is called? I include those variables to control for firm size, on top of the time-invariant fixed effect $\pi_{i}$. I'd be super grateful for any hints!! Many thanks!